# "psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL: role "alvin" does not exist" In postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Im trying to testing a postrgresql In my linux and I have this messege:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  role "alvin" does not exist
```

can somebody help me Im using parrot os

Comment: You are trying to connect with a user that does not exist. You need to provide a username that does. e.g. `psql -U username_that_exists -d db_name`

Comment: To put it another way system user names are not necessarily database user names. I'm guessing you are trying to connect with your system name ```alvin```.